# Create a bookmark to a webpage through non safari browser?

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to create a shortcut or bookmark to a webpage directly from an iPad's main page
which opens in a non-Safari browser.

i.e. Readledocs or GoodBooks?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, now there is no way to do this